# How to set an empty DragView for JavaFX drag board?

Tags: javafx

I'm working on a JavaFX application that involves moving Circles on a Pane.  The code works fine except that when dragging the object, a file icon appears.

I can set the image to a new image using this code within the Circle object's `setOnDragDetected`:

```
Dragboard db = startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.MOVE);
db.setDragView(new Image("/my_image.jpg"));
```

However I don't want any image at all and if I use `db.setDragView(null)`, I get the default file icon again (even though `db.getDragView()==null`).

What's going on here?  How can I disable the use of an image when dragging?

Comment: What exactly is it that you want to do? If it's only moving a circle on a pane, then you don't need the dragview at all. A simple mouse listener would suffice.

Comment: Do you have an example with a MouseListener?  I am only trying to move a circle on a pane and came across the Dragboard approach from a search.  I'm sure I'm missing an easier way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a basic example. I also added a line between the circles to show you how easy it is to bind nodes together:

```
public class DragNodes extends Application {

    public static List<Circle> circles = new ArrayList<Circle>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Group root = new Group();

        Circle circle1 = new Circle( 100, 100, 50);
        circle1.setStroke(Color.GREEN);
        circle1.setFill(Color.GREEN.deriveColor(1, 1, 1, 0.3));

        Circle circle2 = new Circle( 200, 200, 50);
        circle2.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
        circle2.setFill(Color.BLUE.deriveColor(1, 1, 1, 0.3));

        Line line = new Line();
        line.setStrokeWidth(20);

        // binding
        line.startXProperty().bind(circle1.centerXProperty());
        line.startYProperty().bind(circle1.centerYProperty());
        line.endXProperty().bind(circle2.centerXProperty());
        line.endYProperty().bind(circle2.centerYProperty());

        MouseGestures mg = new MouseGestures();
        mg.makeDraggable( circle1);
        mg.makeDraggable( circle2);
        mg.makeDraggable( line);

        root.getChildren().addAll(circle1, circle2, line);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1024, 768));
        primaryStage.show();
    }



    public static class MouseGestures {

        class DragContext {
            double x;
            double y;
        }

        DragContext dragContext = new DragContext();

        public void makeDraggable( Node node) {
            node.setOnMousePressed( onMousePressedEventHandler);
            node.setOnMouseDragged( onMouseDraggedEventHandler);
            node.setOnMouseReleased(onMouseReleasedEventHandler);
        }

        EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMousePressedEventHandler = event -> {

            if( event.getSource() instanceof Circle) {

                Circle circle = ((Circle) (event.getSource()));

                dragContext.x = circle.getCenterX() - event.getSceneX();
                dragContext.y = circle.getCenterY() - event.getSceneY();

            } else {

                Node node = ((Node) (event.getSource()));

                dragContext.x = node.getTranslateX() - event.getSceneX();
                dragContext.y = node.getTranslateY() - event.getSceneY();

            }
        };

        EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMouseDraggedEventHandler = event -> {

            if( event.getSource() instanceof Circle) {

                Circle circle = ((Circle) (event.getSource()));

                circle.setCenterX( dragContext.x + event.getSceneX());
                circle.setCenterY( dragContext.y + event.getSceneY());

            } else {

                Node node = ((Node) (event.getSource()));

                node.setTranslateX( dragContext.x + event.getSceneX());
                node.setTranslateY( dragContext.y + event.getSceneY());

            }

        };

        EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMouseReleasedEventHandler = event -> {
            // nothing to do
        };

    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to have no dragView. I recommend to create an really small image (e.g. 10x10px) which is transparent and use this for the dragView. So you see nothing.